# XmlTextReader - Does it lock the file?

Tags: c#, .net, xmltextreader

This is probably a really simple thing, but I haven't been able to find it, and I'm probably just searching for the wrong thing...

XmlTextReader --> Does it lock the file you're reading?  I'm using reader.Read() and that's about it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you create a new `XmlTextReader` providing a `string`, it will lock the file with a write lock (but not a read lock); however, if you provide it a `Stream`, it would depend on the stream itself.

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"myfile.xml", FileMode.Open,
                            FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
```

You can now read without having a lock.

Comment: +1 beat me to the answer.  Can also do FileStream stream = File.Open(...)

Comment: Yeah, same difference. One probably calls the other (which I don't know, but you could find out with Reflector.)

Comment: Thank you, you are the reason I can finally go to sleep tonight :-) Previously I tried async read, reader.dispose(), none worked. thank you Good night everybody